# Perl - Compare two text files and then match only the difference found on the first file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make a script that would only print the difference in text found in the first file but not in the second file.

For example the first text file contains:

```
a
b
c
d
```

While the second file contains:

```
a
x
y
z
```

With the script that I'm trying, it prints the difference for both the files which is:

```
b
c
d
x
y
z
```

But the result I can't figure out to make is just:

```
b
c
d
```

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $f1 = 'C:\Strawberry\new.raw';
my $f2 = 'C:\Strawberry\orig.raw';
my $outfile = 'C:\Strawberry\mt_deleted.txt';
my %results = ();

open FILE1, "$f1" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line = <FILE1>){
 $results{$line}=1;
}
close(FILE1);

open FILE2, "$f2" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line =<FILE2>) {
 $results{$line}++;
}
close(FILE2);


open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile") or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing \n";
foreach my $line (keys %results) {
 print OUTFILE $line if $results{$line} == 1;
}
close OUTFILE;
```

Comment: Do you care about alignment (eg. compare only line 1 in one file to line 1 in another), or do you want to know if the value in the first file is not found on _any line_ in the second file?

Comment: The second one. If the value in the first file is not found on any line in the second file. Thank you.

Comment: Can any line occur more than once in either file?

Comment: Yes. Some lines occur a couple of times.

Comment: Followup question: So if you have `a` thrice in file 1 and `a` once in file 2, should `a` be printed once or twice? (Include `@ikegami` so I get notified!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add chomp, and assign different value for keys of file2

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $f1      = 'C:\Strawberry\new.raw';
my $f2      = 'C:\Strawberry\orig.raw';
my $outfile = 'C:\Strawberry\mt_deleted.txt';
my %results = ();

open FILE1, "$f1" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while ( my $line = <FILE1> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $results{$line} = 1;
}
close(FILE1);

open FILE2, "$f2" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while ( my $line = <FILE2> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $results{$line} = 2;
}
close(FILE2);

open( OUTFILE, ">$outfile" ) or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing \n";
foreach my $line ( keys %results ) {
    print OUTFILE "$line\n" if $results{$line} == 1;
}
close OUTFILE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by counting the number of occurrences of each line in file 2.

```perl
my %counts;
while (<$fh2>) {
   chomp;
   ++$counts{$_};
}
```

To print each line of file 1 not matched by a line in file 2, simply process file 1 line by line, decrementing the count, and printing the line if the count is negative.

```perl
while (<$fh1>) {
   chomp;
   say if --$counts{$_} < 0;
}
```

---

You said the files could have duplicate lines, but you didn't say how you wanted to handle them. The above handles duplicates as follows:

File 1:

```
a
a
a
b
c
```

File 2:

```
c
a
```

Output:

```
a
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by forming a lookup table of what's in file 2.

```perl
my %seen;
while (<$fh2>) {
   chomp;
   ++$seen{$_};
}
```

To print each line of file 1 not found in file 2, simply process file 1 line by line and printing the line if it's not in the lookup table.

```perl
while (<$fh1>) {
   chomp;
   say if !$seen{$_};
}
```

---

You said the files could have duplicate lines, but you didn't say how you wanted to handle them. The above handles duplicates as follows:

File 1:

```
a
a
a
b
c
```

File 2:

```
c
a
```

Output:

```
b
```